# VueJS Error on sharing data from one component to other

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application

I'm getting some errors in my VueJS application. IMG - http://prntscr.com/exh499
I understand that error exist because `country` property doesn't exist before I load data from weather JSON, but what is the way to remove this error. Also above `[Vue warn]:`

This is the GitHub repo, there is a bit more code so I'm not sure if you can read it here.
https://github.com/DenisLapi/weather-app

Also how to look for changes of some property in Component 2 if I edit that property in Component 1 (I'm usign $emit) but when I define property value in Component 2 and then edit that property in Component 1, usign $emit and props[] seems like value is not updated in Component 2

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render function : (found in <SearchResult> at C:\Users\denis\Desktop\weatherapp\src\components\Result.vue)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

`citydata.foo` is undefined, which is fine, but `citydata.foo.bar` is an error since you're trying to get `bar` off `undefined`.

You should wrap everything using `citydata` with a `v-if` since it's async.

```
<div v-if="citydata">
  <!-- Now you can use `citydata` safely. -->
</div>
```

Comment: I just updated my repo. I removed that part with `v-if` 
But I'm not sure if that is the reason of that error & warn

Comment: The error is talking about this line: https://github.com/DenisLapi/weather-app/blob/master/src/components/Result.vue#L3

Answer (score 0):

Edited: fiddle with a working example https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/24/

BTW, there is no 'country' property in JSON output: [example](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Beirut&units=metric&appid=760b3c85f98b0a077dbb3b5e2ba51b6f)

---

You can

1. set `default` values for your props: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation
2. check properties presence before using them in templates (`v-if` on content blocks)

About reaction on props change: use `computed property` which depends on prop value, or even `watch` prop changes: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers (it depends on your needs)

Comment: I added computed and watch property but not I'm getting some new errors:
1) with watch- http://prntscr.com/exid9e
2) with computed - http://prntscr.com/exiesl but json is loaded (No result.vue page) 

https://github.com/DenisLapi/weather-app/blob/computed/src/components/Result.vue

Also I'm a bit confued about `default` prop values. I have one main prop `citydata` but I have a log of props inside it `sys` `main` `weather` - array etc..

Comment: Your `watch` section is not how it should be done. I've created a fiddle for you with a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/24/ By the way, `country` property doesn't exist in your api response, and will always be undefined.

Comment: I removed watch, I'm using this way: `{{citydata.sys.country}}`
http://prntscr.com/exiv3z But I'm sure that `country` exist in JSON - because I see the value of that property.

I think I'm getting this error because until I load some data from URL , `citydata` object in `Result.vue` is empty in but that page is loaded and `{{citydata.sys.country}}` is executed even though the `citydata` is empty (without `sys.country` properties)

So when I submit my request with city name I don't get that error. 
But I want to prevent that bug when app start with work.

Comment: @DenisLapiLapadatovic this is `sys.country`, you're right. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/25/ - no errors in here, async data fetching.